# SVN to GIT migration resulting in huge size of GIT Repo

Tags: git, svn

I executed the below commands on the Git server to migrate a Subversion repository to a Git repository:

```
mkdir xyz.git
git init --bare xyz.git
svn git clone http://x.y.x.y/svn/CLF xyz.git

du -sh xyz.git
```

After doing this the size of the Git repo is showing double the size of the Subversion repo. 
Did I run the migration incorrectly?

Comment: Git likes to operate on the assumption that storage is cheap and worth trading off for quick performance. Being larger doesn't necessarily mean anything went wrong.

Comment: Now might be a good time to run The BFG to clean unwanted objects out of your history..http://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/

Comment: Could you show the output of `git count-objects -v`?

Answer (score 2):

There is a project that helps you to convert svn to git, https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git. This uses git-svn.  But as it sounds like you've already performed the clone (which can take a while) perhaps take a look at the guide here as just using git-svn clone is imperfect:

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-and-Other-Systems-Migrating-to-Git

But in answer to your question, git repositories can vary in size depending on whether they are packed or not. The *loose* format allows for more rapid access to the repo, and the packed format is, as you might expect, smaller. You can get git to pack the repository by executing:

```
git gc --prune=now --aggressive
git repack
```

This also truncates a facility called the reflog which keeps track of how your edits have changed over time.  This is typically used when working with the code, not performing an export in this way.

You should find when the repository is fully packed it is smaller than the full subversion repository.

Comment: I installed svn2git and my svn repositories doesn't follow the standrard folder structure so i used the below command

     svn2git -v http://192.168.4.201/svn/CLF --rootistrunk
and i got the below error

    error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.
command failed:
2>&1 git checkout -f master

Please assist.

Comment: Means that it has not created master out of trunk. I've not experienced this issue, but others have: https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git/issues/41 Trying a quick test to see if I can reproduce.

Comment: Try providing the `-v` flag to see the order of the commands.  It should output the git-svn init command as it is executing it.